# How to define generic type in Scala?

Tags: scala, slick

In Slick 2, we can map tables like this:

```
case class Cooler(id: Option[Int], minTemp: Option[Double], maxTemp: Option[Double])

/**
 * Define table "cooler".
 */
class Coolers(tag: Tag) extends Table[Cooler](tag, "cooler") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def minTemp = column[Double]("min_temp", O.Nullable)
  def maxTemp = column[Double]("max_temp", O.Nullable)

  def * = (id.?, minTemp.?, maxTemp.?) <> (Cooler.tupled, Cooler.unapply _)
}

object Coolers {
  val tableQuery = TableQuery[Coolers]
}
```

because I have a lot of tables, I want to define generic methods for them, like `find`, `delete`, `update` so I have to define these methods in a super class from where to extend my objects (`object Coolers extends TableUtils[Coolers, Cooler]`). In order to define those methods, I need `tableQuery` to move out of my object in this super class, so I tried it like:

```
abstract class TableUtils[T <: Table[A] , A] {

val tableQuery = TableQuery[T]  

}
```

but I receive an error on `tableQuery` definition:

`class type required but T found`

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do `TableQuery[T]` you are in fact calling `TableQuery.apply`, which [is actually a macro](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/242f74e1a09fd0f6a034ed7ebed653b11d6db712/src/main/scala/scala/slick/lifted/Query.scala#L235).

The body of this macro tries to instantiate `T`, but in your case T has become an (unknown) type parameter that the compiler does not know how to instantiate. The problem is similar to trying to compile this:

```
def instantiate[T]: T = new T
// Does not compile ("class type required but T found")
```

The net effect is that `TableQuery.apply` can only be used on concrete types.

You **could** work around that [using a type class to capture the call to `TableQuery.apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183000/scala-reflection-to-instantiate-scala-slick-lifted-tablequery/30354736#30354736) (at the point where the concrete type is known) along with an implicit macro to provide an instance of this type class. Then you would have something like:

```
abstract class TableUtils[T <: Table[A] : TableQueryBuilder, A] {
  val tableQuery = BuildTableQuery[T]
}
```

Where `TableQueryBuilder` is the type class and `BuildTableQuery` is an alternate version of `TableQuery.apply` that will forward to the `TableQueryBuilder` instance to perform the actual instantiation.

I've added an implementation as part of [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183000/scala-reflection-to-instantiate-scala-slick-lifted-tablequery/30354736#30354736).

It will be much easier (if less convenient) to just declare `tableQuery` as an abstract value and define it in every concrete derived class of `TableUtils`:

```
abstract class TableUtils[T <: Table[A] , A] {
  val tableQuery: TableQuery[T, T#TableElementType]
  // define here your helper methods operating on `tableQuery`
}
object Coolers extends TableUtils[Coolers, Cooler] {
  val tableQuery = TableQuery[Coolers]
}
```

Comment: Using the last method, I receive the following error: `wrong number of type arguments for TableQuery, should be 1`. Is there anything special to consider when implementing it? Or is there a working implementation of it?

Comment: THey seem to have changed `TableQuery`  between version `2.0.0-M3` and `2.0.0`. Try replacing `val tableQuery: TableQuery[T, T#TableElementType]` with `val tableQuery: TableQuery[T]`

Comment: I have actually implemented the type class (`TableQueryBuilder`) solution for a related answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30354736/1632462

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

At first, define this to avoid class type issue..

```
class Service[T <: Table[_]](path: String, cons: Tag => T){

  lazy val db = Database.forConfig(path)

  def query = TableQuery[T](cons)
}
```

Then use it this way, Post is sub class of Table:

```
object Abcd {

  object Def extends Service[Post]("mydb", abc) {



    def test = {


      //db

      val q = query.drop(1).take(20)
      val r = db.run(q.result)

      println(q.result.statements.head)
      println(r)

      r

    }
  }

  private def abc(tag: Tag) = new Post(tag)

}
```

This solution tested ok in slick 3.x, and Play slick 1.x, since the slick 2.0 Query.scala comply to slick 3.0 Query.scala, this might work at 2 too.