# Scala reflection to instantiate scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery

Tags: scala, reflection, slick

I have this base trait

```
trait MyBase {
  type M
  type T <: Table[M]
  val query: TableQuery[T]
}
```

Where `TableQuery` is `scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery`

My subclasses instantiate `TableQuery` like so:

```
type M = Account
type T = AccountsTable
val query = TableQuery[T]
```

I'd like to instantiate the `TableQuery` in the base trait, possibly by using a `lazy val`, i.e.

```
lazy val query: TableQuery[T] = {
  ...
}
```

I've been playing around with reflection, but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but what is the purpose of instantiating the TableQuery in the trait (it is hard to understand the value, because, it will be different for every type that works with the trait) - perhaps adding this might add more context for someone to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to be able to extend 
`MyBase` by simply defining `M` and `T` but without having to explicitly instantiate the `TableQuery` in each derived class.

Using reflection is not really an option because normally you use `TableQuery.apply` 
for that (as in `val query = TableQuery[MyTable]`), and this is implemented through a macro, 
so you've got a "runtime vs compile-time" issue.

If you absolutely need `MyBase` to be a trait (as opposed to a class), then I don't see any viable solution.
However if you can turn `MyBase` into a class **and** turn `M` and `T` into type parameters (instead of abstract types), then there is at least one solution.
As I hinted in another related question ([How to define generic type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090228/how-to-define-generic-type-in-scala/20093938#20093938)), you can
define a type class (say `TableQueryBuilder`) to capture the call to `TableQuery.apply` (at the point where the concrete type is known) along with an implicit macro (say `TableQueryBuilder.builderForTable`) to provide 
an instance of this type class. You can then define a method (say `TableQueryBuilder.build`) to actually instantiate the `TableQuery`, which will just delegate to job to the type class.

```
// NOTE: tested with scala 2.11.0 & slick 3.0.0
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros
object TableQueryBuilderMacro {
  def createBuilderImpl[T<:AbstractTable[_]:c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._
    val T = weakTypeOf[T]
    q"""new TableQueryBuilder[$T]{
      def apply(): TableQuery[$T] = {
        TableQuery[$T]
      }
    }"""
  }
}
trait TableQueryBuilder[T<:AbstractTable[_]] {
  def apply(): TableQuery[T]
}
object TableQueryBuilder {
  implicit def builderForTable[T<:AbstractTable[_]]: TableQueryBuilder[T] = macro TableQueryBuilderMacro.createBuilderImpl[T]
  def build[T<:AbstractTable[_]:TableQueryBuilder](): TableQuery[T] = implicitly[TableQueryBuilder[T]].apply()
}
```

The net effect is that you don't need anymore to know the concrete value of the type `T` in order to be able to instantiate a `TableQuery[T]`, 
provided that you have an implicit instance of `TableQueryBuilder[T]` in scope. In other words, you can shift the need to know the concrete value of `T`
up to the point where you actually know it.

`MyBase` (now a class) can then be implemented like this:

```
class MyBase[M, T <: Table[M] : TableQueryBuilder] {
  lazy val query: TableQuery[T] = TableQueryBuilder.build[T]
}
```

And you can then extend it without the need to explcitly call `TableQuery.apply`:

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Double)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME")
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def * = (name, price)
}

class Derived extends MyBase[(String, Double), Coffees] // That's it!
```

What happens here is that in `Derived`'s constructor, an implicit value for `TableQueryBuilder[Coffees]` is implicitly 
passed to `MyBase`'s constructor.

The reason why you cannot apply this pattern if `MyBase` were a trait is pretty mundane: trait constructors cannot have parameters, let alone implicit parameters, so there would be no implicit way
to pass the `TableQueryBuilder` instance.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this answer together. A lot of great information here.

Comment: Although this is a great solution, still I'm struggling to find how to abstract a simple `db.run(query.result)` as result cannot be resolved. Is there anyway to implement some kind of Data Mapper with Slick at all? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. You might want to post a proper question with the relevant code snippet demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Great! This answer is very helpful for me!