# Scala Slick single filter for multiple TableQuery instances

Tags: scala, reflection, slick-3.0, cake-pattern

*I'm using Scala Slick-3.1.0 lib*.

How is it possible to make a generic Slick filter function that takes TableQuery instance as an input and makes same slick filter on it?

I have several case classes (two for example) representing data stored in DB.
Some fields are the same so classes could possibly extend common ancestor:

```
case class FirstData(symbol: String,
                     date: Timestamp,
                     firstField: Double) 

case class SecondData(symbol: String,
                      date: Timestamp,
                      secondField: String)
```

Each of them has its own SQL Table in DB and is represented by separate Slick `Table` class. Also they have same primary keys:

```
class FirstDataTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[FirstData](tag, "firstData") {
    def symbol = column[String]("symbol")
    def date = column[Timestamp]("date")
    def firstField= column[Double]("firstField")
    def * = (symbol, date, firstField) <> ((FirstData.apply _).tupled, FirstData.unapply)
    def pk = primaryKey("pk_firstData", (symbol, date))
}

class SecondDataTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[SecondData](tag, "secondData"){
    def symbol = column[String]("symbol")
    def date = column[Timestamp]("date")
    def secondField= column[String]("secondField")
    def * = (symbol, date, secondField) <> ((SecondData.apply _).tupled, SecondData.unapply)
    def pk = primaryKey("pk_secondData", (symbol, date))
}
```

Finally `TableQuery` classes are:

```
val firstDataTableQuery = TableQuery[FirstDataTable]
val secondDataTableQuery = TableQuery[SecondDataTable]
etc ...
```

How is it possible to make a generic Slick filter query function that takes  `firstDataTableQuery` or `secondDataTableQuery` as an argument and makes same slick query on input. Filtering only on their common fields or another way saying on their SQL Table representations common columns. For example like this:

```
def filter(genericTableQuery: TableQuery) = {
    genericTableQuery.filter { data => dataFilterFunction(data.symbol)
    }.filter(_.date >= someDate).sortBy(data => data.date.asc)
}

val firstTableResult = filter(firstDataTableQuery)
val seconfTableResult = filter(secondDataTableQuery)
etc ...
```

I looked on this topics, but still could not make up a solution:

[Slick 3 reusable generic repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522128/slick-3-reusable-generic-repository)

[Scala reflection to instantiate scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183000/scala-reflection-to-instantiate-scala-slick-lifted-tablequery/30354736#30354736)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4191629/invariant), thanks a lot. You pointed me to the right direction. I slightly modified your answer and everything works )

Traits:

```
trait Data {
            def symbol: String
            def date: Timestamp
            }

trait GenericDataTable[T <: Data] extends Table[T] {
            def symbol: Rep[String]
            def date: Rep[Timestamp]
            def pk: PrimaryKey
            }
```

FirstData and FirstDataTable classes look like this:

```
case class FirstData(
            symbol: String,
            date: Timestamp,
            firstField: Double) extends Data

class FirstDataTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[FirstData(tag,"firstData") 
    with GenericDataTable[FirstData] {
            def symbol = column[String]("symbol")
            def date = column[Timestamp]("date")
            def firstField= column[Double]("firstField")
            def * = (symbol, date, firstField) <> ((FirstData.apply _).tupled, FirstData.unapply)
            def pk = primaryKey("pk_firstData", (symbol, date))
    }
```

Finally function looks like this:

```
private def filter[M <: Data, T <: GenericDataTable[M]] (genericTableQuery: TableQuery[T]) = {
            genericTableQuery.filter { data => dataFilterFunction(data.symbol)}.
            filter(_.date >= someDate).sortBy(data => data.date.asc)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making the data table classes extend a common trait, which in turn extends a common trait for data classes, like for example:

```
trait Data {
  def symbol: String
  def date: Timestamp
}
// make FirstData and SecondData extend the above trait

trait GenericDataTable extends Data {
  def symbol: Rep[String]
  def date: Rep[Timestamp]
  def pk: PrimaryKey
}


class FirstDataTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[FirstData](tag, "firstData") with GenericDataTable {
// ...
```

and then:

```
def filter[T <: GenericDataTable](genericTableQuery: TableQuery[T]) = // ...
```